# Moving Thunderbird from Windows 7 to a Mac

Tags: mac, thunderbird

I am a new mac user and would like to move all my thunderbird email to my macbook pro.

How do I do this?  How do I find out where T-bird stores the data.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/profile) handy Thunderbird help document on profiles gives you all the information you need.

> - On Windows Vista/XP/2000, the path is usually %AppData%\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\, where xxxxxxxx is a random string of 8 characters. Just browse to C:\Documents and Settings[User Name]\Application Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\ on Windows XP/2000 or C:\users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\ on Windows Vista, and the rest should be obvious.
> - On Windows 95/98/Me, the path is usually C:\WINDOWS\Application Data\Mozilla\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\
> - On Linux, the path is usually ~/.thunderbird/xxxxxxxx.default/
> - **On Mac OS X, the path is usually ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/**

It also contains information on how to move and backup your profile.